# How to escape echo?

Tags: social-sharing

I have just added few social media icons to share the current post. So the code is below for pinterest (example purpose). But the reviewer said echo should be escaped.

Why the reviewer pointed it to escape the "echo" and what is the way to do so...

```
<!-- pinterest -->
<a href="https://pinterest.com/pin/create/bookmarklet/?media=<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>&url=<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>&is_video=false&description=<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" target="blank"><i class="fab fa-pinterest-square"></i></a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Do not use echo because WordPress has already defined it.
So use it as given below:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
<?php the_permalink(); ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
```